# Multiple Date Range selection in Mat datepicker

Tags: javascript, angular-material

I have been trying to find an open source date picker to select multiple date ranges in one popup and use it in an angular project.
Is it possible to achieve this functionality in Mat Date range picker
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#date-range-picker-forms
or if there is any other solutions. Thanks